# Only part of CSS file is getting loaded in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

For some reason my page is only loading part (about 1/3 of my `CSS` file). It is a concatenated and minified. If I go to **http://staging.easyuniv.com/styles/dbf42ab5.main.css**  I can see the whole thing.

The weirdest part is that if look at sources in Chrome Dev Tools, about a third of the way it goes blank (right in the middle of a class name), but then you can scroll the rest of the way as if the text were there.

I am loading it on my page with the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/dbf42ab5.main.css">
```

Anyone ever run into anything like this? I've run out of things to try.

Comment: Simple question: is this a caching issue? Try a 'deep reload' a few times.

Comment: Can you post a link to the CSS file?

Comment: Any error messages you get? What is in the log files?

Comment: You should also post some code as how you include the css file.

Comment: updated, and I get no errors in the console, where else should I look?

Comment: I see that the CSS ends with `html body.easyzag #container .content #ad-divider{background-image:url(../images/zag-divider.png)}` Is that where you see it cutting off? If you're working this hard on concatenating and minifying, maybe you set your cache settings too strict?

Comment: its getting cut off in the middle of the icon section of the bootstrap css. I just have default cache settings (as far as i know) I'm using yeoman for the first time and just running into some trouble

Comment: This is strange. I am seeing the same thing here trying to load that CSS on a page.

Comment: Did it work fine before the minification?

Comment: well, I didn't try it on the server, but yes locally it did

Comment: @TroyCosentino i don't know how hard you need it, but it seems there is a newer version [**2.3.0**](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).

Comment: Are you actually missing any CSS on the page itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The file is [far from valid](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http://staging.easyuniv.com/styles/dbf42ab5.main.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en) which should probably be looked at but here's what I've found…

- I cannot paste the contents of your CSS file into http://cssbeautify.com/ - the CSS is cut off in almost the same place as Chrome is doing
- I can paste into http://www.codebeautifier.com/ which can generate a CSS file that will load just fine! Very strange.

Through some trial and error it seem that a CSS file that is concatenated **on a single line** looks like it has been cut off when using the Chrome Developer Tools. The file seems to have been parsed as using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and searching for something at the end of the file (I was searching for `zag-divider`) then Chrome is reporting that it is found, although the found count seemed wrong.

Specifically, it seems that **any line** of this CSS file that is >= 66,537 characters will be cut off! For example:

- a single line CSS file <= 66,536 characters will not be cut off
- a single line CSS file >= 66,537 characters will be cut off
- a multi line CSS file >= 66,537 characters will have only lines that are >= 66,537 will be cut off

I had a single line of exactly 66,537 characters of CSS which was cut off, but by adding a single carriage return after the first selector and reloading, the entire file was shown correctly in the Console.

So to summarise… a CSS file with any line >= 66,537 characters looks like it has been cut off part way through in the Chrome Developer Tools although the file has actually been loaded fully. I tested this by adding a rule to the end of the line which was applied by Chrome.

*Note: I would have been happier if the seemingly magic number was 2<sup>16</sup>*

*Edit: Investigation carried out on Chrome 23.0.1271.97 m*

Comment: **+1** for the nice analyse !

Comment: So there is a limit of characters per line?? Good pointer there indeed +1

Comment: @Monkieboy it seems that there is a _display_ limit per line in Chrome Dev Tools (or a bug!). The CSS from the whole line still seems to be applied correctly

Comment: @andyb these seem to all be errors in twitter bootstrap.. but I have used bootstrap many times (so have others) with it working fine.. I ran the non-minified version of bootstrap through the validator and got around the same number of errors

Answer (score 4):

For googlers having this problem but not exclusively using Google Chrome, may be useful verify that truncation doesn't be result of a known [pitfall of Nginx and virtualization](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#virtualbox), that could be resolved disabling `sendfile` in your server block.

You could find more about this problem in this article: http://www.conroyp.com/2013/04/25/css-javascript-truncated-by-nginx-sendfile/

Answer (score 1):

I have tried running it through some parsers:

http://www.codebeautifier.com

http://www.cssportal.com/css-validator

Unfortunately they cannot seem to read completely through your css file, you should run your css through them as the results are too big to post here. I think when you minified there may have been many things that could have happened, wrong encoding, spaces moved that were actually necessary.

From the results the parsers provided I would suggest you revert back to the unminified version and start again because the errors I have seen here are too numerous ( over 900 were identified) for you to try and 'fix' the css.